# How to call a function with a parameter typed high-dimensional array by passing a pointer?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a function like (need c99)

```
void fun(int nx, int ny, double a[nx][ny])
{
    // some code here
}
```

and I have a pointer

```
double *p = new double[nx * ny];
```

and use it to call the function like

```
fun(nx, ny, p); // error for the type is not matched
```

How to do it? Any type conversion is allowed.

Comment: Of course.  A pointer to a double is fundamentally not the same as a 2D array.

Comment: you are passing a pointer to  single dimensional array, theres no way this can work like that

Comment: Your function fun takes in a 2D array of doubles, whereas you are defining p as a 1D array of doubles. This is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible in C++ because C++ requires the sizes of array types to be compile time constants. C99 does not have this limitation, so the function declaration

```
void fun(int nx, int ny, double a[nx][ny]);
```

is valid C99, but not valid C++. Btw, in C99, the correct call of this function would look like this:

```
int nx = ..., ny = ...;
double (*matrix)[ny] = malloc(nx*sizeof(*matrix));
fun(nx, ny, matrix);
```

Now, you have two possibilities:

1. Use C for your multidimensional array stuff.
2. Use a C++ workaround for this.

---

The easiest C++ workaround would be a `vector<vector<double> >`. With that you avoid the hassle of allocating the memory yourself, however, the rows in your 2D matrix are not consecutive.

---

You can also use a two layer indirection like this:

```
double **matrix = new double*[nx];
for(int i = 0; i < ny; i++) matrix[i] = new double[ny];
```

and declare your function as

```
void fun(int nx, int ny, double** a);
```

Note that you need one additional index array in addition to the arrays that hold the data. However, you are free to use a single large array to hold the data:

```
double** matrix = new double*[nx];
double* storage = new double[nx*ny];
for(int i = 0; i < ny; i++) matrix[i] = &storage[ny*i];
```

---

The final possible workaround is, to do the index calculation yourself:

```
void fun(int nx, int ny, double* twoDArray) {
    //access the array with
    twoDArray[x*ny + y];
}

//somewhere else
double* matrix = new double[nx*ny];
fun(nx, ny, matrix);
```

This is exactly what C99 does under the hood with the code at the top, but with significantly less type checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void fun(int nx, int ny, double** a){
// some code here
// Get the element in this way: double myD = a[i][j];
}
```

And in Main:

```
double** a = new double*[nx];
for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
{
   a[i] = new double[ny];
}
```

And call the function:

```
fun(nx, ny, a);
```

or if you want to pass an array:

```
void fun(int nx, int ny, double* a){
int dim = nx*ny;
double myD = a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass a 1d array (or a pointer to one) to a function that's declared to take a 2d array.

If you need to allocate a 2d array dynamically, what you can do is:

```
// ny can be runtime variable in c99, but must be compile time constant in c++
constexpr int ny = 10;
int nx = 10;
double (*p)[ny]  = new double[nx][ny];
fun(nx, ny, p);
```

If you want to use your 1d array as is, you'll need to modify `fun` to accept a 1d array instead:

```
// note that double a[] or double* a param would be identical, nx*ny is just for documentation
void fun(int nx, int ny, double a[nx*ny])
     // access indices [i][j] like this: a[nx*j + i]
```

In c++ however, I would recommend you to hide any dynamic allocation behind an abstraction that will manage the memory. Say, a `Matrix` class in this case.